# Attaching persistent disks makes Google compute instance inaccessible

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I followed the docs on google from scratch, (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk)

to mount a persistent disk to my compute instance, it all goes well till I add it to the /etc/fstab as the doc suggests.

`` echo UUID=`sudo blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/disk/by-id/google-[DISK_NAME]` /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR] ext4 discard,defaults,[NOFAIL] 0 2 | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab ``

if I do a reboot after this, my instance will become un-ssh-able. (even though it shows as running in the console)

I repeated the exact same steps on a centos 7 image, 5-6 times from the scratch from new instance, and every single time, the echo to fstab makes my instance inaccessible. horrible horrible doc. but I still wanna know how I can fix it ?

Comment: Happened to me as well, when I tried to 'make it simpler' by mounting the disk to `/mnt/[MNT_DIR]` instead of the advised `/mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]` - perhaps you're doing something similar?

Comment: No I did everything the doc said step by step, I did no changes or innovations.